# SharePoint 2013: Document Check out to local draft folder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document, check-out, check-in

I am using **SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Server** and a team site. I try to **Check Out** and **Edit** the file from document library to **Local Draft Folder**. This document library is enabled document version and required check out setting is on. I have already added this site to **Trusted sites**.
But the document can not **checkout** from document library and **checkin** to document library. Document can not check Any suggestion is appreciated.

*Sorry for previous certificate error screen shot.*

Comment: Although I'm not sure it's the cause of your problem, but has the SharePoint url been added to "trusted sites" or "local intranet" security group?

Comment: Hi Andreas, Yes I have already added to "Trusted sites". Thanks for reply.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you mean by "local draft folder"? When does the security alert occur?

Answer (score 0):

This error may be from a mismatched cert on the SharePoint server, or a alternate access mapping url that is different from the way you are browsing the SharePoint server...

Make sure the default zone is the url you are browsing with.

Comment: Hi Mike, I think your comment might correct because I am using host header to my site collection and using both http & https. I configured at AAM Default Zone (http://myhostheader/sites/mysitename) and at Intranet Zone (https://myhostheader:447/sites/mysitename). I browse with https://myhostheader:447/sites/mysitename. I will try tomorrow and if this is worked, I will mark as answer to your answer.. Is there any possibilities? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mike, even I change https:// myhostheader:447 to **Default Zone** , the error is still same. Thanks!

Comment: Why is your port 447?

Comment: I have 3 SSL sites using different ports and different host name. 443,446 & 447

Comment: Why not have all on port 443? Using non-standard ports are not recommended.